# Click on ASP .Net Core Identity Log In button leads to 400 error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-identity

I'm writing simple **asp .net core 2.2 MVC** app with individual authorization (ASP Identity) hosted on **IIS 10**. If user navigates to Login page, **stays idle for 20+ minutes** (which is IIS default timeout to terminate app pool) and  click on log in button - browser gets a **400 response** and shows blank page. If user updates (F5) login page before click to log in - everything works fine.
IIS pool settings all default, but pipeline is changed to No Managed Code.
APS Identity Code default too (only registration modified a little).
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this idle login case?

I tried to disable AntiForgery Token Validation but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you mean each user should refresh the login page or just the first request?  I mean the IIS application pool will stop if it doesn't receive the request for some time. If the new request come in, it may takes much time than before.

Comment: I meant if user: 1. opened login page, 2. entered login and password and didn't click login button 3. do nothing for 20+ minutes 4. after idle time period click on login button - browser gets 400 error and shows blank page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue. On my app pool settings **loadUserProfile** was set to **False** by default. After I changed it to **True** everything started to work fine.
Don't know why it cause problems in False state though.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] from the method(for which pag in MVC application.